# Hibernate error null ID after DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have some code which try INSERT in multi-threaded  environment:
https://gist.github.com/iva-nova-e-katerina/9aa6c6bce74c13aa3f074462cae33240
In the line 14 of the method.java I getting an exception:

```
org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.agas.infra.datamodel.logic.chat.JPAChatContact entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.checkId(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.getValues(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
```

what am I trying is to insert unique OWNER or update if it already exist (in catch block).
Why Hibernate think that there is null-id in the database?